# 'virtual xyz' vs 'xyz virtual' methods

Tags: c++, virtual

What's the difference between:

```
class A {
public:
void virtual method1() {...};
virtual void method2() {...};
};
```

The compiler (Edit: Apple LLVM 3.0)is not complaining about it. I know that method1 is not a virtual method (talking about polymorphism), then what is it?

thanks

Comment: I think the question suggested as a duplicate is not really right.

Comment: oops!  You're right!  @subzero: Why do you say that `method1` is not a `virtual` method?  It looks `virtual` to me!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how you order them. You can write funny stuff like

```
struct A {
  void virtual inline f() {}
  int static const unsigned value = 0u;
  int const typedef value_type;
};
```

The compiler doesn't care. The Standard doesn't care either.